# How to display arrays as Jsx elements in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-react

There is this users array in which the user names are stored in the photo are split from the photo array and i want to display the array results as buttons are displayed . The code snippet is below

```
let users: string[] = [];
const setUserNames = photo.filepath.split("_")[1];
users.push(setUserNames);
console.log(`Name ->`, users);
return (
   <IonRow>
     {users.map((users, index) => (
        <IonButton key={index}>{users}</IonButton>
      ))}
    </IonRow>
)
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(users)` line print? It would be helpful if you could provide some more info, what you are trying to achieve. :)

Comment: It’s not clear what you are trying to do which isn’t being done already.  But you will only ever have 1 user in the users array, and consequently only one button, because you are only pushing the element at index [1].  If there are multiple usernames in the file name then you need to add them all to your users array.

Comment: Console.log(users) print that user names in the array

Answer (score 0):

Be careful,

`users.push(setUserNames)` is mutable and doesn't adhere to the way data is changed in React. You need to change `user` using `useState` and spread operators.

Moreover, I'd advise you do all your array building in the seperate function and return a `user` array and then set that array to some state using `useState`.

Then start building the UI using `JSX`

Something like this.

```
const SomeCom = (props) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(buildUserArray(props.photos))
    return (
        users.map(() => {
            // Render your JSX
        })

    )
}
```

Comment: Hey the function buildUserArray how to create that ?